# MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream (Java to Mongo using ssl)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, ssl

I am getting the mentioned error when trying to connect my java app with the mongo cluster with ssl true.
Below are the steps which I am following :

> Note: The used path are the dummy data I used the actual or correct
>   path for each.

1. Created my own Java Key Store.
2. Import CAFile in keystore using below cmd:
   "%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\keytool -import -trustcacerts -file "..\..CAFile.pem" -keystore my-keystore -storepass test@123
3. Now convert my PEMKeyFile.pem into .pkcs12 formate 
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in "..\..PEMKeyfile.pem" -out ..\..PEMKeyfile.pkcs12
4. Java code:

```
@Bean
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
     System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","..\\..\\my-keystore");
     System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","test@123");
     System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","..\\..\\PEMKeyfile.pkcs12");
     System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","test@123");

     MongoClientOptions  mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).build();    

     MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, db, pwd.toCharArray());
     return new MongoClient(return Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("host-1", 123),
             new ServerAddress("host-2", 123),
             new ServerAddress("host-3", 123));, credential, mongoClientOptions);
 }
```

Error:
same error coming for all three hosts

```
INFO 4088 --- [xyz:27051] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server host-1:123

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was by mistake I removed one certificate form actual generated pem file and when I was trying to connect through terminal it was able to connect with a single certificate but when the same thing tried in code I don't know why and how it changed the nature all of sudden it stops working so it was not easy to detect what part is faulty but yes after just undoing my generated pem file with two certificates it worked.